# How to open an activity using custom URI?

Tags: android

I am trying to start an activity within my app from a custom uri returned from my service.

For example my service is going to return me something like: "activity2".  Basically I want to start the activity that has the correct filter listening for the "activity2" intent. I am kind of stuck on how I would do this. Can anyone give me an example of some sort?

In my Activity2 declaration I put this as an intent filter but it doesnt seem to work:

```
<intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="activity2"/> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="foo"/> 
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser

Comment: That is great for setting it up. But how would I be able to trigger it  via an intent, not just when a user clicks on a link?